# Angular 11 library use paths alias

Tags: angular, angular-library

I created project in Angular11 with a library and an application under folder `projects`:

```
-> Test
----> node_modules
----> projects
--------> test-lib
--------> test-app
```

When I created `test-lib` automatically it creates a new path alias in `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "es2020",
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ],
        "paths": {
            "test-lib": [
                "dist/test-lib/test-lib",
                "dist/test-lib"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created some components and also a file called `_exports.ts` in the same components folder. This file contains only a list of exports. I exported this file in `public-api.ts` and now I'm able to use components in `test-app` in this way:

```
import { MyComponent } from "test-lib";
```

To make order in the code I added another alias in `paths`:

```
"test-lib/components": ["dist/test-lib/components/_exports"]
```

In `test-app` I can import components using this alias but when I compile application I get this big error:

```
Error: ./projects/test-app/src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'test-lib/components' in 'PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\projects\test-app\src\app'
resolve 'test-lib/components' in 'PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\projects\test-app\src\app'
Parsed request is a module
using description file: PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\package.json (relative path: ./projects/test-app/src/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\package.json (relative path: ./projects/test-app/src/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\dist\test-lib\package.json (relative path: ./components/_exports)
        no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\dist\test-lib\components\_exports doesn't exist
        .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\dist\test-lib\components\_exports.ts doesn't exist
        .tsx
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\dist\test-lib\components\_exports.tsx doesn't exist
        .mjs
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\dist\test-lib\components\_exports.mjs doesn't exist
        .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\dist\test-lib\components\_exports.js doesn't exist
        as directory
        PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\dist\test-lib\components\_exports doesn't exist
    resolve as module
    looking for modules in PATH_TO_FOLDER/Test
        using description file: PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\package.json (relative path: .)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        using description file: PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\package.json (relative path: ./test-lib/components)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\@test-lib\components doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\@test-lib\components.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\@test-lib\components.tsx doesn't exist
            .mjs
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\@test-lib\components.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\@test-lib\components.js doesn't exist
            as directory
            PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\@test-lib\components doesn't exist
    PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\projects\test-app\src\app\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\projects\test-app\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\projects\test-app\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\projects\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    PATH_TO_FOLDER\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    ...
    looking for modules in PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\node_modules
        using description file: PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        using description file: PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/test-lib/components)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\node_modules\@test-lib\components doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\node_modules\@test-lib\components.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\node_modules\@test-lib\components.tsx doesn't exist
            .mjs
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\node_modules\@test-lib\components.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\node_modules\@test-lib\components.js doesn't exist
            as directory
            PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\node_modules\@test-lib\components doesn't exist
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\dist\test-lib\components\_exports]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\dist\test-lib\components\_exports.ts]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\dist\test-lib\components\_exports.tsx]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\dist\test-lib\components\_exports.mjs]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\dist\test-lib\components\_exports.js]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\@test-lib\components]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\@test-lib\components.ts]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\@test-lib\components.tsx]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\@test-lib\components.mjs]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\@test-lib\components.js]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\projects\test-app\src\app\node_modules]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\projects\test-app\src\node_modules]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\projects\test-app\node_modules]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\projects\node_modules]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\node_modules]
...
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\node_modules\@test-lib\components]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\node_modules\@test-lib\components.ts]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\node_modules\@test-lib\components.tsx]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\node_modules\@test-lib\components.mjs]
[PATH_TO_FOLDER\Test\node_modules\@test-lib\components.js]
@ ./projects/test-app/src/app/app.component.ts 2:0-46 39:26-32
@ ./projects/test-app/src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./projects/test-app/src/main.ts
@ multi ./projects/test-app/src/main.ts
```

When I import from `test-lib` it works fine but with my alias it doesn't. How can I create an alias that works in my `test-app`?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the paths in the following way:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
   ...
        "paths": {
            "test-lib": [
                "dist/test-lib/test-lib",
                "dist/test-lib"
            ]
            "test-lib/components/*": [
                "dist/test-lib/test-lib/components/*",
                "dist/test-lib/components/*"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

also use `index.ts` instead of `exports.ts` as your barrels export.

Comment: This solution doesn't works. I get the same error. By the way, * force me to create one line of code for any single import. I want a single import for components, single import for models and so on

Comment: Ok I'll try that on my local machine asap